# Pandigital Novel running Android Eclair - Need User Manual - How do I access the External SD card?

Tags: applications

I have a Pandigital Novel with Android Eclair, but I have no user manual for it. How do I access the external SD card? There is no app to do this, and no Device Manager or My Computer built into the operating system, except Astro, which only gives access to the internal SD card.